# Image Swap using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, swap, animated-gif

I hope somebody could help me out with this.
I'm working on a portfolio website that currently looks like this:

http://cargocollective.com/shap

As you can see, I have a png image over 15 animated gif thumbnails.

Basically, I want to have some short gif animations popping into some of the screens from a time to time, so what i'm trying to do is to have a script that replaces some of the gifs with others, either randomly OR after a certain amount of time.

I hope that someone can understand what i mean and help me.

______________________ **UPDATE**:

Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the help. I'm sorry for the lack of knowladge I have, making it hard for me to use what you just wrote there, but this is what I added to my source code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  changer();
});

function changer() {
  var imgnum = Math.floor(15 * Math.random());
  var time = Math.floor(5000 * Math.random());
  var $img = $("img").eq(imgnum);

  if ($img.attr("src") == "http://payload.cargocollective.com/1/1/39798/479556/prt_166x132_1314132436.gif")
    $img.attr("src", "http://payload.cargocollective.com/1/1/39798/479849/prt_166x132_1314132538.gif");
  else
    $img.attr("src", "http://payload.cargocollective.com/1/1/39798/479556/prt_166x132_1314132436.gif");
  setTimeout(changer, time);
}
```

```css
/* have any CSS? put it here! */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>woops need some HTML here</div>
```

I just copied the URL of 2 of my gif thumbnails and added them to the script, is that absolutely wrong?
Maybe the fact that I'm using the cargocollective system makes things complicated.
Here is what it looks like right now, as you can see, something IS happening, but I can't really control it:

http://cargocollective.com/shap

(after a minute the png overlay is gone for whatever reason)

best,
s

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Try writing some code and then asking a question on that code. We can't just help you if we have no idea where you are in the process.

Comment: This web will be just amazing! nice design btw... ( @Amir - I agree )

Comment: I created a snippet of what you posted alas it needs some HTML and perhaps CSS to be of much use.  Alas your link seems to only produce a 404

Answer (score 1):

Tube televisions! How wonderfully quaint. ;-)

Well, here's something I tossed together. Obviously you should change the actual image SRCs into something that exists on your server.

http://jsfiddle.net/9KrsV/1/

```
$(function() { changer(); });

function changer() {
  var imgnum = Math.floor(15*Math.random());
  var time = Math.floor(5000*Math.random());
  var $img = $("img").eq(imgnum);

  if ($img.attr("src")=="images/chalk-dotted.png")
    $img.attr("src","images/chalk-box.png");
  else
    $img.attr("src","images/chalk-dotted.png");
  setTimeout(changer,time);
}
```

UPDATE: Obviously, this is pretty narrow. Here's another script that will store the old SRC and eventually flip back to it:

```
function changer() {
    var imgnum = Math.floor(15 * Math.random());
    var time = Math.floor(5000 * Math.random());
    var $img = $("img").eq(imgnum);
    var newsrc = "noisy_static.gif";

    if ($img.attr("src") == newsrc) {
        $img.attr("src", $img.data("oldsrc"));
    } else {
        $img.data("oldsrc",$img.attr("src"));
        $img.attr("src", newsrc);
    }
    setTimeout(changer, time);
}
```

Comment: should be `setTimeout(changer,time);`

Comment: my comment was too long to post, so I just edited the original post. Any chance I can squeeze out some more information out of you? Thanks a lot for the help so far.

And i'm sorry I can't come to you with a few lines of self written code, I just can't find anyone who is able to help me with this.

Comment: Added another suggestion. Anything more than this and I'll have to start billing hours to you, though.